# Why cannot open activity inside of custom pager adapter in Android?

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

I am developer an Android app. In my app, I am creating custom image pager using pager adapter. What I want is I want to start image activity when I click on the current image of pager. So I tried to start the activity inside adapter. My pager is working fine except starting activity. But when I start activity, it is throwing error. How can I fix it?

This is my pager adapter and how I start activity inside it:

```
public class ItemImagePager extends PagerAdapter{
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    ArrayList<String> mResources;

    public ItemImagePager(Context context,ArrayList<String> urls) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mResources = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image_pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_item_image_pager);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mResources.get(position)).into(imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ViewImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("url",mResources.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

This is the logcat when I start activity clicking the image:

```
04-10 11:05:37.698 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-10 11:05:37.742 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6184908)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:952)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:939)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.model.ItemImagePager$1.onClick(ItemImagePager.java:54)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 11:05:38.938 28934-28934/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where did you create this adapter ? inside an activity ?

Comment: Yes. Inside an activity and I passed getBaseContext() to first parameter.

Comment: Use the activity itself as the context will solve the problem. ex: MyActivity.this instead of getBaseContext()

Comment: No I cannot do that because I set it inside the click event. Moreover I cannot notify data change like list view adapter when the data is changed.

Comment: "No I cannot do that because I set it inside the click event." - Yes you can do that. You must specify the `Activity` class, like TinTran shows. Just `this` won't work.

Comment: Thanks u for helping me all. I got the answer and I upvoted. It was my weakness in checking error. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add - FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to your intent:

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Or you should try by adding flags:

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: I tried like thiis. But it is not working as well. Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ViewImageActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("url",mResources.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(i);

Comment: Now u should try instead of set flags use addFlage

Comment: Sorry. This worked. I got errors with the next activity. Sorry for my weakness in logging error. Thanks.

Comment: Great !! Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

`mContext` is not an `Activity`, apparently. It should be, just as you should be getting `mLayoutInflater` by calling `getLayoutInflater()` on an `Activity`, so your theme is respected. <strike>And, since you are not implementing any of the normal `View` constructors, it is clear that you are the one creating your instance of `ItemImagePager`, rather than the framework doing it (e.g., by inflating some layout).</strike>

So, your options are:

1. Change your code that creates the `ItemImagePager` to pass in an `Activity` as the first parameter (and, ideally, fix that `LayoutManager` bit), or
2. Read the error message and do exactly what it tells you to do: add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent`

Comment: `ItemImagePager` is an Adapter, not a `View`.

Comment: @MikeM.: Ah, good point. It's too early here. Strikethrough applied. Thanks!

Comment: I passed getBaseContect() to the first parameter to the activity and I set i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  to my intent. But it is still not working.